# How to add language code after domain name on nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, magento2.2

I would like to add `en-us` language code on URL. The expectation is as follows.

When a user hits on http://example.com/, page should redirect users to http://example.com/en-us/
Note: I have achieved this with the following code.

```
location = / {
      rewrite ^ /en-us/ redirect;
  }
```

How to redirect customers to following scenarios

- http://example.com/contact, should redirect to http://example.com/en-us/contact
- http://example.com/en-us/, it shouldn't append extra en-us in url.
- http://example.com/en-in/, it shouldn't append en-us in url.

Simply, what i want to achieve is if there is no `en-us` in url, then we should add en-us in XX-XX place. http://example.com/XX-XX/contact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Do nothing for assets (paths with a dot)

location ~ \. {
}
```

You can match locations that *don't start with the required path* by using a negative lookahead regex (`?!`)

```
# Paths that don't start  with /en-us/ are redirected:

location ~ ^(?!/en-(us|in)/) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /en-us/$1 redirect;
}
```

Or using an `if` block:

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^/en-(us|in)/")
{
    return 301 /en-us/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and its working well. I have added 1 more scenario (3rd point). Is it possible to restrict the url appending?

Comment: Yes, have the regexes include in as well.

Comment: Thank you it's working as expected. But one more problem is coming, i don't want to append this language code in js and css urls. It results, the page is not rendering properly. I want this redirect to work only for website URLs, not static files. It will be great if we have the option like that.

Comment: You can match against static assets and have an empty block

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the [rewrite documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)? There are many similar examples there.

This is I'd do that (untested).

```
# Do not redirect /
location = / {
}

# Redirect everything else to /en-us/...
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /en-us/$1 redirect;
}
```